# Correct JNDI @Resource(name)

Tags: java, jboss, jndi

I have the following class for obtaining a JDBC connection:

```
package util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class OracleConnection implements AutoCloseable{

private final String oracle_DS_CTX = "java:jboss/oracleDS"; 

    //  @Resource(name="java:jboss/oracleDS")
    //  private DataSource ds; //doesn't work   

    private Connection _conn;   

    public OracleConnection() throws SQLException, NamingException{

            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(oracle_DS_CTX);
            _conn = ds.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
            if(_conn != null){
                    _conn.close();
            }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
            return _conn;
    }
}
```

I have a problem using the `@Resource` annotation. Datasource obtained via InitialContext works without any problems but I am not sure what string should I put into resource name (commented out in my code).

I have tried:

`@Resource(name="java:jboss/oracleDS")`

`@Resource(name="oracleDS")`

AS is JBOSS AS7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What name did you define in your `standalone.xml`?

That is the name you need to define in your `@Resource`

But there's a little trick, you need to set it in the `lookup` property instead of `name`.

Here's an example, let's assume my DS jndi is `java:jboss/ExampleDS`.

```java
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/ExampleDS")
private DataSource dataSource;
```